# Exporting module value

Tags: node.js, typescript, sails.js, waterline

I am confused.  I have the following javascript file:

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'freshairMysqlServer',
  tableName: 'Accounts',
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  autoPK: false,

  attributes: {
    idAccounts: {
      type: 'integer',
      primaryKey: true
    },
    AccountName: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    idOrganization: {
      type: 'integer'
    }
  },

  GetAccounts: function (page, cb) {
    Accounts.query('SELECT Accounts.AccountName as AccountName,' +
      ' Organizations.Name as Organization FROM Accounts' +
      ' JOIN Organizations on Accounts.idOrganization = Organizations.idOrganizations',
      function (err, results) {
        if (err) cb(err)
        else cb(null, results);
      });
  }
}
```

The module exports a javascript object, {connection: ..., tableName: ..., ...}.  This value is used by Sails to extend a Waterline model object.

What is the TypeScript code that accomplishes the same?  I have tried several variations but don't seem to be getting it.  Help!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var objectToExport = {
  connection: 'freshairMysqlServer', ... };
export = objectToExport;
```

and be sure to compile with `--module commonjs`

Comment: Ooops!  No it doesn't work.  I was testing the wrong file.  The query returns a server error in the Typescript version.

Comment: I just checked.  The value of the module for the suggested solution is the same as the value of the original module.  I have no clue why the original module works but the suggested solution does not.

Comment: @LaurenceDrews did you by mistake replace a `function` with `()=>` by chance ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA